# Gentoo installation and DHCP issues

Tags: linux, router, bios, dhcp, gentoo

I am trying to install Gentoo from the minimal install disc on my old 32-bit Lenovo T60 laptop. After getting past the initial install screen to the minimal install CD shell I got a DHCP error and was unable to connect to the internet (through ethernet). After that error I decided to reserve an IP address on my router thinking that might work around my DHCP error and when I turned the laptop back on I got a black screen on boot up that says:

```
ERROR 
0271: Check date and time settings 

Press <F1> to Setup
```

Does anyone know how I can reset the system so I can start the installation over? If I figure out how to reformat the HD will that fix my issue?

My router is running tomato, is it somehow possible that the default DHCP server on tomato is unable to assign the minimal CD an IP address? Would I be better off using a different router with conventional firmware? Does anyone think that setting the IP static on the client might also fix the DHCP problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your battery for the RTM back up on the laptop has died, which reset the clock.

This is just a bios warning that the clock is incorrect and telling you. Simply hit F1, then go into the bios and check the clock.

Once you've finished installing gentoo, you can setup ntp to override whatever time the RTM returns, if it's truly dead, or try replacing the battery.